# How do I install HP CentOS repo's

Tags: linux, centos6, hp

I have been searching for the answer but unable to find any instructions that work for me.

I want to install the HP CentOS repo for my new ML310e Gen8 Server to I can setup the insight management software etc for it.

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're looking for the [HP Software Delivery Repository (HP-SDR)](http://downloads.linux.hpe.com). The [process to install it is documented pretty well here](http://downloads.linux.hpe.com/SDR/getting_started.html).

I do this via Puppet, but running it manually is no big deal either:

There's the HP Management Component Pack (MCP) and the HP Support Pack for ProLiant (SPP). CentOS is technically supposed to use the MCP, while Red Hat is supposed to use the SPP. I just use the HP SPP for everything.

In your case, just download the **[add_repo.sh](http://downloads.linux.hpe.com/SDR/add_repo.sh)** script. The script is silly in that it requires the `redhat-lsb` package to be installed. In the end, your command will look like:

```
# sh add_repo.sh -d RedHat spp
```

Once that's done, you can install the HP agents via yum. For your server, I'd recommend something like: `yum install hp-snmp-agents hpssa hp-health hp-smh-templates hpsmh hpssacli hponcfg` and maybe `yum install kmod-hpahcisr` in case you have a Dynamic Smart Array controller.

Full command usage:

```
[root@mdmarra ~]# sh add_repo.sh 

  Usage: add_repo.sh <RepoName>

    eg: where <RepoName> might be "spp" (Support Pack for Proliant)
        or any directory found in http://downloads.linux.hp.com/SDR/repo

    Normally the distribution, version, architecture and other information
    is auto-detected.  You made override these attributes with the following:

         [ -a <Architecture> ]     override to specified Linux architecture
         [ -d <Distribution> ]     override to specified Linux distribution
         [ -r <Release> ]          override to specified Linux release

         [ -R <Revision> ]         override to specified product revison

         [ -o <OutputDirectory> ]  override default output directory
         [ -s <APTConfigFile> ]    override default APT configuration file
         [ -y <YUMConfigFile> ]    override default YUM configuration file
         [ -z <ZYPPConfigFile> ]   override default ZYPP configuration file

         [ -m <TransportMethod> ]  override default transport protocol
                                   (ftp or http)
         [ -w <WaystationHost> ]   override default waystation host
         [ -u <URLPrefix> ]        override default URL prefix
```